# How do I use prepared queries using the mysql2 package on node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

The example given in the documentation is as follows:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ user: 'test', database: 'test'});

connection.execute('SELECT 1+? as test1', [10], function(err, rows) {
  //
});
```

The idea here is that the "?" in the query gets replaced with the value of "10". This example shows how to use the query once with the replacement value of "10". How can I use the prepared query multiple times with different replacement values? The hope here is that a prepared query has been compiled and so multiple invocations of that query will not incur the performance hit of compiling the query each time it is run.

thanks - Gary

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the statements are really prepared and cached, as suggested by [the source code](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/94ca2b49c68b96e9459ecb41a2bb3415b70047db/lib/commands/execute.js#L26-L35):

```
Execute.prototype.start = function(packet, connection) {
  var cachedStatement = connection.statements[this.query];
  if (!cachedStatement) { // prepare first
    connection.writePacket(new Packets.PrepareStatement(this.query).toPacket(1));
  } else {
    this.statementInfo = cachedStatement;
    return this.doExecute(connection);
  }
  return Execute.prototype.prepareHeader;
};
```

This is confirmed by [this comment](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/274#issuecomment-30503391) on the issue of `node-mysql` that talks about `node-mysql2`, by the author of the library:

> its prepared once and can be used many times.

This comment thread also talks about the eviction politic of the prepared statements: LRU or MRU, which is in agreement with the fact that `node-mysql2` does indeed prepare and cache the statements (and this is even noted as a TODO in the [source code](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/167bc5ae6aef958930d3482f3315274742e008bd/lib/connection.js#L38)).